# CSS and Javascript files not updating in Production environment

Tags: javascript, html, css, caching, umbraco

System's not able to recognized any changes in my CSS and javascript files that are deployed from staging to production environment. I'm sure that I'm editing the correct file and path, even test alert is not working. It looks like the files have been cached but after clearing my cache, still no luck.
We're using Umbraco CMS. Any idea? Am I missing anything?

[image: loading of files:]

Comment: I would try renaming the files or appending a time-based query string to the file as well, then check the console for client side requests, it's also worth checking in another browser than the one you use default. Also, maybe the CMS does some caching that you can disable that might be the cause. Possibly related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28455506/umbraco-cache-problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@lyka you can try adding a version on your js links

```
<script src="/scripts/prechat/emea-locale-json.js?v=20160223" type="text.javascript"></script>
```