# Different Rendering VS IISExpress vs Production IIS

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, iis, razor

I have a website maintained locally in IIS 10. Built in VS 2017. The files are identical - I copied them there myself. On the IISExpress via Visual Studio debug or regular run the web page will center my object  kind of stuff - works as it should.
However in production server this will not center no matter what I have tried to do.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

Setting response Header in IIS , = edge or = Edge neither works ..

I have the same result regardless of what browsers I use , IE, Firefox, Chrome .. so I am at a great loss and pulling me hair out (I don't have much hair to begin with ... Micros..t could be stockpiling it for some alter evil plot).

What on Earth do I need to do in order to make this work or at least find the culprit.. Why will it not center , other objects center.

Answer (score 0):

If the webpage content is not centered, the possible reason is that the CSS is not correctly applied to the web page.
Please Press `F12` to check if there exist certain browser errors when opening the web page in the browser. Please post it as part of your question.
Besides, it is recommended to publish the content of the website by using VS Publish menu so that the CSS static folder could be accessed properly by the `IUSR`account which has minimal permission to access the website content. Without the proper folder access permission to the web content, the web page will display incorrectly, such as the usage of static files, CSS/JS files. Please ensure that the IUSR account has full control of the root directory of the web application(Read/Write permission).
[image]
Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.

Comment: I followed the guide for Umbraco 8.6.3 in moving from development to production. I set user permissions for IIS_IUSRS and also IUSR .. other pages render just fine. Only the one page does not. I see the exact same css styles in the inspector. I know it has to be reading in order to have the styles there. In F12 there are no errors (none). This is why I have been delving down the rendering meta - as I have searched and found plenty on SO and other sites that seem to indicate that IIS is forcing the rendering. Why on that page only I don't know. IIS express works.

Comment: Can you directly navigate to the CSS file in the browser on the server?  Try to clear the local cache in browser to see if it works. In addition, try to remove certain client dependencies on front end. 
I am not familiar with the Umbraco product. It seems that this kind of issue is universal. See these links.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35173147/css-and-javascript-files-not-updating-in-production-environment

Comment: Tried clearing the browser cache on all browsers. The file is accessible or my other pages would not render correctly. This one is a redirected page after email contact success, so I am not sure if it has something to do with that .It really is a PIB. right now I have left it off for another day. Javascript files load fine no issues.